# para que sirve _("") en django

Tags: python, django, django-models, vscode

Esto empezando a usar el framework django y uso visual studio code como editor de texto, agregue una extención y a la hora de escribir modelos y usar el autocompletado siempre me aparece lo siguiente **"`_("")`"**.

Ejemplo:

```
models.CharField(_(""), max_length=50)
```

Y no eh visto nada en la documentacion que diga para que sirve, a si que no se si es necesario borrarlo o dejarlo ahi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está relacionado con el concepto llamado ["internacionalización"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/) (abreviado a "i18n" porque hay 18 letras entre la "i" y la "n").

Para que tu programa pueda ser fácilmente traducido a otros idiomas, no debería usar cadenas literales normales, así: `"Hola"`, pues si quieres pasarlo a inglés deberías andar buscando por todo el código todas las cadenas que haya y cambiarlas una a una (y además, en ese caso, el programa dejaría de estar en Español, no tendrías un programa que pueda tener la interfaz en el idioma que elija el usuario).

Por ello se usa en cambio `_("Hello")`. La sintaxis no es mágica aunque lo parezca, sino que simplemente se está invocando una función llamada `_` (es un nombre válido de identificador) que recibe como parámetro la cadena, en un idioma concreto, normalmente el inglés, y que la sustituye por su traducción al idioma que en ese momento tenga elegido el  usuario.

> En realidad `_()` es un alias para la función `gettext()` y Django recomienda usar esta última para evitar sobreescribir el significado de la variable `_`, que por defecto en python representa el resultado de la última expresión evaluada. [info aqui](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/)

Las traducciones se escriben en ficheros aparte, un fichero para cada idioma, en el que aparecen las cadenas en inglés ("Hello") al lado de sus traducciones ("Hola"). El framework se ocupa de cargar estos ficheros cuando sea necesario para que la función `_()` pueda usarlos.

En el caso de tu IDE, entiendo que en los lugares donde se espera que pases un string, automáticamente te pone `_("")` para recordarte que debes usar esa función si quieres que tu programa admita i18n.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, muy bien explicado. No creo tener la necesidad de usar esta herramienta ya que es un proyecto sencillo para una materia, pero si sigo programando en python utilizando Django, seguramente sea algo que llegue a utilizar